# Regarding the input in {} on Console.Write("{0,3}", i+1);

Tags: c#, for-loop, methods

Guys, I hope you're all doing fine.
So, the code is:

```
Console.Write(" ");
        for (int i = 0; i < _temperatures.Length; i++)
        {
            Console.Write("{0,3}", i+1);
        }
```

Does the input in braces represent some sort of bounds or does it have to do with sign/unsigned?
I've looked for this construction everywhere and even read all those code letters for the format variant, and I failed to found one where you use , instead of : and where you add 1 to the counter like that. I know the output will be a space, then the numbers from 1 - 12 (representing the months); but how?

There's another place where I see a similiar use of the construction:

```
for (int i = max; i >= min; i--)
        {
            Console.Write("{0,2}", i);

            for (int j = 0; j < _temperatures.Length; j++)
            {
                if (_temperatures[j] >= i)`
...
```

what happens next isn't a problem, I understood it. But in the beginning, it starts with 18 (that's the max temperature in in the array of length = 12), then it goes over the loop, then goes down by one (i--) - I get it. But what does the stuff in {} mean?

Btw: the min temperature is -2.

Could you please tell what I have to understand in order to understand this construction?

I appreciate any help.

Thanks

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/composite-formatting

Answer (score 1):

> Does the input in braces represent some sort of bounds or does it have to do with sign/unsigned?

[It's a Composite Format String. Please read the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/composite-formatting).

`{0,3}` means it should render the 0th (i.e. the first) format-argument and right-align it with spaces so it's a minimum of 3 characters wide.

```
Console.WriteLine( 123 )            => "123"
Console.WriteLine( "{0}", 123 )    => "123"
Console.WriteLine( "{0,5}", 123 )  => "  123"
Console.WriteLine( "{0,4}", 123 )  => " 123"
Console.WriteLine( "{0,3}", 123 )  => "123"
Console.WriteLine( "{0,2}", 123 )  => "123"
Console.WriteLine( "{0,1}", 123 )  => "123"

Console.WriteLine( "{0,5}", 12 )  => "   12"
Console.WriteLine( "{0,4}", 12 )  => "  12"
Console.WriteLine( "{0,3}", 12 )  => " 12"
Console.WriteLine( "{0,2}", 12 )  => "12"
Console.WriteLine( "{0,1}", 12 )  => "12"
```

Comment: Dai, thank you very much for the quick reply. 
Things I noticed: 
- This is a .NET feature, and I was reading the C# documentation. It may mention this kind of formatting somewhere anyway, but I didn't find it. I saw only the letter codes and using full colons. HAHA 
- As you may have noticed, I am a beginner. I had already seen the kind of formatting using that letter code and : to get  numbers in a specific format, and with a certain # of decimals, for example, but I hadn't read yet about this alignment feature. I now can read the code and understand it. 

Again, thank you very much.

Comment: @Kelarov FYI: C# is *one* of the languages available on the .Net platform.

Comment: That I knew. F#, C# and VB, right? 
I was, however, reading a C# Guide dotnet/csharp ... and I just couldn't find what I was looking for. The link Dai provided is a dotnet/standard .. and no, I was not there. One may think I didn't read it properly, but I did. Once Dai sent me the link I found the construction I was looking for haha. 
So, it was on this dotnet standard stuff, that's why I said it was a platform feature, not a language one. I don't know if that's how one should say it though, but I hope you get what I mean. Thanks for the comment ><